# Hide the main menu for CMS Pages in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, topmenu

Hide the main menu for home page and main menu display for another pages in magento2.?

Answer (score 1):

The homepage has an unique class on the body element, like: "cms-home".

After you identify that class, add a css property to hide the menu in a css file that is included on homepage, like this:

```
.cms-home .navigation {display: none;}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For hide main menu in CMS pages add below style:

```
.cms-page-view .nav-sections {display: none;}
```

And if you want to remove the main menu for all CMS pages add the below code in `app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Themename>\Magento_Cms\layout\cms_page_view.xml` file.

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
```

**AND**

If you want to remove the main menu for Home page add the below code in `app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Themename>\Magento_Cms\layout\cms_index_index.xml` file.

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Hi @Dipesh Rangani, i have added customer links into nav section (menu bar), but its hiding, when i inspect element all the codes available, i just did <move element="header.links" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/> any help thanks.

Comment: Hi @zus,  There is default Magento CSS `.nav-sections-item-content>* { display: none; }`  that's why you have to add css for `display: block;` for perticular element. You can refere screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/wb85fe.

Comment: can you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Comment: We can use layout update of the cms page (home). More Info: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html